# How do I request a basic authentication token from my firebase realtime database using axios?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, axios, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime database in which I have setup the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "blogposts": {
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

I have also setup a user under Authentication using basic authentication (email/password).

What I'd like to know is how to set auth in the write rule above to not null.

I've read the Firebase documentation and they recommend using the Firebase admin SDK. Nothing wrong with this but I've already setup my backend to fetch and post data with axios. In order to not have to refactor the backend to use the Firebase admin SDK and to keep consistency, I'd prefer to use axios for authentication.

Therefore, my question is: is there a way to send a request to my Firebase project using axios to authenticate with my Firebase user's email and password and get a token back?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the Realtime Database REST API to access the database using credentials from a Firebase Authentication account?  Would you like to share the code you have now that's working without authentication and security rules, so we can see where you're at?

Comment: Sure. Here's how I submit a post: axios.post('/blogposts.json', post).then(response => {res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({id: response.data.name}));});

Comment: Have you read through the documentation that discusses how to pass an auth ID token in the request? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

Comment: Yes, but the documentation says "To retrieve the ID token from the client, make sure the user is signed in and then get the ID token from the signed-in user," and it proceeds to show how to do this using Firebase Admin. I'd like to know 1) how to sign in (I'll tackle using the token after), 2) how to use axios to do this rather than Firebase Admin.

Comment: You sign in with the client SDK for the platform you're using.  If your app isn't signing in the user, what you're trying to do is impossible, because you won't have an ID token for that user.